# Unable to mock dao in service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have written junit 5 for service and controller but I am not able to mock service and dao. Its calling actual method of service and dao class.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {UserService.class})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(RefreshAutoConfiguration.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @MockBean
    private ReadDao readDao;

    @Test
    public void getDataTest() {

        Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("Admin", new User(1,"john"));
        when(readDao.getData(any())).thenReturn(userMap);

       User user = service.getUserData();
    }
}
```

UserService

```
@Component
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private ReadDao readDao;

    @Value("${app.user.role}")
    private String role;

    public User getUserData() {
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = readDao.getData("name");
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            //do nothing. return empty 
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

@MockBean is not create mock object, its creating actual object so call goes to dao layer.
Am I missing anything? Same happened with controller, when I tried to mock service its calling actual method of service class.

Comment: It's not clear why you are making this a `@SpringBootTest` instead of just a normal junit test. Please edit your question to show your `UserService` class.

Comment: Share us a reproducible sample

Comment: after removing the @SpringBootTest getting same result

Comment: If you remove @SpringBootTest you'll need to make other changes to turn it into a normal Mockito based unit test.

Comment: You must not run this test with `@MockitoExtension`, only with `@SpringBootTest` (you are using `@MockBean` from Spring Boot, not `@Mock` from Mockito)

Answer (score 0):

This test does not need to start the whole Spring context. It should be a simple, straightforward Mockito test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    UserService service;

    @Mock
    private ReadDao readDao;

    @Test
    public void getDataTest() {

        Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("Admin", new User(1,"john"));
        when(readDao.getData(any())).thenReturn(userMap);

       User user = service.getUserData();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried also but not sure why my control goes to dao layer, also not getting value from property file

Comment: Yes, that test won't inject `role` -- but it's unused in your code.

Comment: not is this test but its used in another test

Comment: I prefer constructor injection to make tests simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject the dependencies through constructor instead of Autowire in your UserService, then you can write a simple junit test without loading the whole spring context

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private ReadDao readDao;

    @Value("${app.user.role}")
    private String role;

    public User getUserData() {
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = readDao.getData("name");
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            //do nothing. return empty 
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now your test class will look like this

```
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class})
public class UserServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    UserService service;

    @Mock
    private ReadDao readDao;

    @Test
    public void getDataTest() {

        Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("Admin", new User(1,"john"));
        when(readDao.getData(any())).thenReturn(userMap);

       User user = service.getUserData();
    }
}
```